# make wordpress posts change content dynamically

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to customise a wordpress blog post so that it changes slightly based on the User?

eg. when showing a post around Salary and Bonuses on the company blog, I'd like to customise some of the text based on the employee level (director, Executive etc) - for example:

- a paragraph of text about pension contribution should only appear to
  directors reading the page
- the bonus amount should change based on employee level.

I don't want to create several pages per category (eg. one page for the directors, one for the execs etc) - I would like to have just one blog post with some variable fields?

Answer (score 0):

The codex has a great function outlined, `current_user_can`
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can

As well as `WP_User_Query`
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query

You can use both of these to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do something similar, I came up with custom roles based on the plugin "Capability Manager Enhanced".

In a file you can check the roles like:

```
 <? if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>

                    <?
                        global $current_user;
                        get_currentuserinfo();
                        $roles = $current_user->roles;  //$roles is an array

                        if ( is_user_logged_in() && in_array("custom_role", $roles)  ) {
                            echo('WORK HARDER!');
                        } else {
                            echo('NO CAKE FOR YOU!');
                        }

                    ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```